# Is there a feature for data bound formset?

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have created an editable formset with mutltiple fields of the same type.

The data can be edited and submitted.

Is there a way to bind this formset to the data so that updates happen automatically? or

Do I need to iterate over all the editable fields and update them individually?

Comment: It's easy - just change line 9. Oh, whoops, you haven't shown any code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% what you're asking, but is your data coming from a Model? If so, You can have formsets tied to ModelForms using **model formsets**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

So if you have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(...)
    field_2 ...
    ...
```

and a model form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_1 = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    field_2 ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

You can create a formset from that model. Something along the lines of this:

in your **views.py**

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductForm)
if request.method=="POST":
    formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
    ...
else:
    formset = ProductFormSet()
...
return direct_to_template(request, 
    template = "foo.html",
    extra_context = { 'formset' : formset })
```

This is useful as the models will automatically get updated when the formset is POST'ed and validated. It also knows when a particular instance has been edited in the formset, so you can do further logic.

Comment: I just came across this post looking for a way to do just this, but when I call .save() on the formset, I get an exception that the formset has no attribute save.  Is there something missing from this example, or was this something that was removed at some point from Django?

Comment: I don't have time to look over it at the moment, but you can loop through each form in the formset and save each particular form separately

Comment: That is indeed what I wound up doing.